# How can I limit the maximum width of an element in a WrapPanel to the width of the WrapPanel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a `WrapPanel` into which I have placed some `Grid`s, into which I have placed some `TextBox`es, similar to the following:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <!-- Other label / text box pair grids -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="FancyLabel" Margin="1,1,1,0"/>
        <TextBox Name="FancyValue"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Margin="1,1,1,0"
                 Text="{Binding}"
                 MinWidth="45"
                 Width="Auto"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 AcceptsReturn="False" />
    </Grid>
</WrapPanel>
```

If the user enters text that is too long, rather than wrapping to an extra line, the `TextBox` expands its width off the screen rather than respecting `TextWrapping`, similar to the following:

[image: Example UI]

Is there a mechanism to limit the maximum width (preferably without data binding to `ActualWidth` on the `WrapPanel`)?

Comment: that's a strange behavior of textbox, but have you tried to prevent the changes in width of textbox using Sizechanged event, if not by databinding?

Comment: @RohitPrakash: Yes, I could do binding or code-behind to fix this. But any such solution is likely to be brittle. Pretty much every time I've run into formatting problems like this WPF has had some sort of attached property or something I wasn't aware of that did what I was looking for. If it doesn't exist that's fine; but I wanted to ask before I hacked something together.

Comment: use TextTrimming..  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: hmm very strage is it possible for you to post your xaml part?

Comment: `<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" Text="{Binding Notes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />`

Comment: @Anirudth: `TextTrimming` is a `TextBlock` thing, not a `TextBox` thing.

Comment: @Abin: Yep, that's what I've got. But `ActualWidth` on the `TextBox` ends up being far wider than `ActualWidth` on the `WrapPanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rob DeLuca for sending me something that works outside of SO:

Changing the `Auto` on the second column to `*` instead wraps correctly:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <!-- Other label / text box pair grids -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!-- !!! -->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="FancyLabel" Margin="1,1,1,0"/>
        <TextBox Name="FancyValue"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Margin="1,1,1,0"
                 Text="{Binding}"
                 MinWidth="45"
                 Width="Auto"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 AcceptsReturn="False" />
    </Grid>
</WrapPanel>
```